# Travis espresso test fal java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci, android-espresso

I updated the Android API on which Travis will run the tests on from API 22 to API 24 and since then I can't get my tests to run anymore. I keep getting this error output for all of my tests:

```
com.simplemobiletools.calculator.MainActivityTest > divisionByZeroTest[test(AVD) - 7.0] FAILED 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not request layout for 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Root:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2409854, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2409854, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#100 ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x1030465 needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=800, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#100 ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x1030465 needsMenuKey=2}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}}
```

Here is my travis.yml looks like this:

```
{
  "sudo": false,
  "language": "android",
  "android": {
    "components": [
      "tools",
      "platform-tools",
      "build-tools-27.0.2",
      "android-27",
      "android-24",
      "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-24",
      "add-on",
      "extra"
    ]
  },
  "licenses": [
    "android-sdk-license-.+"
  ],
  "jdk": "oraclejdk8",
  "before_install": [
    "echo yes | sdkmanager \"platforms;android-27\" \"build-tools;27.0.2\""
  ],
  "before_script": [
    "echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-24 --abi armeabi-v7a",
    "emulator -avd test -no-window &",
    "android-wait-for-emulator",
    "adb shell input keyevent 82 &"
  ],
  "os": "linux",
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "trusty"
}
```

I tried adding/removing the -no-skin and -no-audio tags on the emulator line but to no success. May I get a hint as to what I'm doing wrong here? Cheers!

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? any updates?